# Какой должен быть запрос на удаление определенного количества записей в бд

Tags: mysql, pdo

Никогда с подобным не сталкивался и гугл не особо помог.
Мне нужно из таблицы удалить определенное количество записей.
Например если в базе 10 записей, то нужно удалить начиная с 1 записи и заканчивая 9 чтобы 10 запись осталась не тронутой. сортировка id. в моем случае это id диалога (он одинаковый) в котором идет переписка между двумя пользователями. в итоге мне нужно, при условии что количество записей в бд = 50 (количество всех нужных мне записей я получаю), удалить начиная с 1 и заканчивая 49. 50-я должна остаться.

Answer (score 0):

Синтакис mysql запроса одинаковый.

```
DELETE from table_name where id>=9 and name<=19;
```

На PDO можно так:

```
$start = 9;
$end = 19;
$sql ='DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id BETWEEN :start AND :end) ';
$pdo_statement->bindValue(':start',$start, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdo_statement->bindValue(':end',$end, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdo_statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Запрос на удаление, как и любой другой запрос, может включать в себя инструкцию LIMIT, ограничивающую количество удаляемых записей. См. [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  DELETE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html).

При этом для того, чтобы результат удаления был детерминирован, необходимо также наличие инструкции сортировки набора ORDER BY, причём по выражению, по которому все записи набора уникальны.

Однако если удаляемые записи следует ограничить не по количеству, а по значению некоего поля/выражения, то соответствующий отбор производится в секции WHERE.

Само собой оба ограничения могут накладываться одновременно.